# Expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am trying to show currency related return value in my laravel blade view. Here is the code in my controller

```
        $ip = \request()->ip();
    $data = \Location::get($ip);
    $countries = new Countries();
    $data =  $countries->where('name.common', $data->countryName)->first()['currencies'];
    return view('check', compact('data'));
```

And in my blade view

```
{{$data}}
```

I have tried to see the return value of data like

```
 return $data =  $countries->where('name.common', $data->countryName)->first()['currencies'];
```

and then get the result like

```
[ "BDT" ]
```

Comment: Do you have an error? In that case, please put the full error message into your question, instead of putting half of it into the title! And if it mentions a line number, tell us which line of the code you've shown it relates to, because we cannot see your line numbers.

Comment: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: okay solved For enter `[ "BDT" ]` this location i have to make code like 

    $data =  $countries->where('name.common', $data->countryName)->first()['currencies'][0];

Comment: I think your Countries model has a relation name 'currencies'. isn't it?

Comment: Glad you solved it. That'll be because `['currencies']` returns an array. You can't make an array into a string automatically.

Comment: {{$data['currencies']}}

Comment: okay, thank's to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see `['currencies']` returns an array and you can't make an array into a string automatically.

You can do like this:

```
$data =  $countries->where('name.common', $data->countryName)->first()['currencies'][0];
```